# Nginx Rewrite and redirect a URL

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am struggling trying to rewrite and redirect a URL.

The external URL is www.mydomain:443/app1. The internal URL is https://192.168.1.2:8080. Nginx is running on 192.168.1.1. I have tried several things looking at the docs and the forum.  The code below gets me to the device, but the page comes back blank.  I have tried rewrite and redirect with no luck.

```
location /app1/ {
   if ($request_uri ~* "/app1/(.*)") { 
        proxy_pass  https://192.168.1.122:8080;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm very confused as to a) What your issue is and b) What you're trying to accomplish. Can you try to rephrase your situation and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to redirect external URL requests going to www.mydomain:443/app1 to internal URL https://192.168.1.2:8080.  Proxy_pass will handle the redirect of the IP and port, but I am not sure how to remove the app1 subfolder from the URL request.  Just using proxy pass yields https://192.168.1.2/app1:8080 instead of https://192.168.1.2:8080.  Hopefully that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, I think you mean:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mydomain;

    #Your ssl stuffs here

    location /app {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.122:8080;
        #Other proxy params here
    }
}
```

Comment: However, you say that NGINX is running on `192.168.1.1`. So I assume `localhost` has this IP, which means that you'll need to have something processing request on `192.168.1.122:8080`. You also mention something about `192.168.1.2`. Was this a typo?

Comment: 192.168.1.2 is that appliance that is hosting app1.  Nginx is running on 192.168.1.1.  There is no 192.168.1.122.  Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Standard proxy_pass takes me to generic page saying welcome to nginx.  Rewrite and proxy_pass seems to get me closer.  Page loads but is blank.  Log shows "GET /api/4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 .